# Getting user's location in android app simultaneously

Tags: android, location, friend

I'm planning to make an app which will find my friend's specific location and the coordinates will move as my friend moves. Is there any way other than using his phone number?

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw in a server to achieve this goal. Following flow may help you. To know more about GCM (Google cloud messaging) you can check [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

[image]